# Parse REST Request in SOAPUI Mock Service

Tags: parsing, rest, soapui

I am trying to achieve a very simple goal in soapui
I have created a mock rest service in soapui that I can return static content from if the last resource matches a file name. problem is:

I use Spring RESTTemplate to make a REST call ala:
http://www.sample.com/user/group/{1}/status

where {1} is the only variable (it will be a number like 1111 or 2323)

In the OnRequest script section I should be able to write something simple that allows me to extract this resource from the full url and then craft a return of a static file of the same name ie:

ref = value.at.specified.location.{1}.in.url

return file(ref.xml)

any help translating these 2 pseudo code lines to actual working code would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works:

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
path = groovyUtils.getProjectPath() + "/docroot/" + mockRequest.getPath().tokenize('/')[4] + ".xml";
try
{
    mockRunner.returnFile(mockRequest.httpResponse, new File(path));
    mockRequest.httpResponse.status = 201
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    mockRequest.httpResponse.status = 403
}
return new com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockResult(mockRequest);
```